# how can i get the center Point of sqlgeometry arc?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, geometry, sqlgeometry

i have Mssql database i'm storing some geometry in database as sqlgeometry 
i work in mvc4 project with EF5 i have arcs store in the databse
i can get it form database as dbgeometry  then convert it to sqlgeometry for some reasons i want to get the centerpoint of this arc ?
is there is free geometry .net lib to calculate that for me?

the is my sample code that build the arc geometry from 3 point on arc

```
            SqlGeometryBuilder geomBuil = new SqlGeometryBuilder();

        geomBuil.SetSrid(32637);
        geomBuil.BeginGeometry(OpenGisGeometryType.CircularString);
        geomBuil.BeginFigure(startPoint.X, startPoint.Y);
        geomBuil.AddCircularArc(PointOnArc.X, PointOnArc.Y, endPoint.X, endPoint.Y);
        geomBuil.EndFigure();
        geomBuil.EndGeometry();

        SqlGeometry arc = geomBuil.ConstructedGeometry;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 points at circle - startPoint, PointOnArc and endPoint. To find circle center, you can use formulae from **Circumcircle equations** [section here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle).

Comment: I,m asking for free geometry lib that do that ,, I already did it by solving the circle eqs but the solution isn,t accurate may floating point accuracy